# Getting the following error in my code: @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Tags: java, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Im trying to show an image after getting a random value from a list, but I am getting the following error in the Button OnClick part of my code when I try to use the showFlag function - @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function. I'll show the main areas that are being affected.

Code:

```
package com.example.courseworkone

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import java.util.Random




@Composable
fun DisplayGUI() {
    Column(){
        Button(onClick =
        {
            showFlag()
        })
        {
            Text("Guess the Country")
        }
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text("Guess-Hints")

        }
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text("Guess the Flag")
        }
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text("Advanced Level")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun showFlag() {
    val imagenum = getRandomCountry()
    if (imagenum.isNotEmpty()) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = getResourceId(imagenum)),
            contentDescription = "Country Image"
        )
    }
}
```

Attempted removing composable from the showFlag function
Attempted putting the contents of the showFlag function into the Button itself

Comment: `Image()` is a `@Composable`. You cannot call a Composable in an `onClick` function. Think about where do you want this `Image` to display? Putting it in an `onClick` function doesn't make it show up anywhere because an `onClick` function is not a `@Composable`, not in the compose tree. Put the `Image()` directly inside `DisplayGUI`, and the `onClick` function is only responsible for updating the state `imagenum`.

Comment: `@Composable` function is no where near regular function. Better think of them as two different languages. `@Composable` function does not "do stuff", it is more of a mark up language like HTML, JSX etc. , describing the layout of the UI with states. While regular function perform certain operations. Don't mix them up.

Answer (score 1):

there is a simple solution you have to use it oftenly in compose,

**here is the modified code**

```
@Composable
fun DisplayGUI() {
var showFlagVisible by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
Column(){
    Button(onClick =
    {
     //update the variable here, to show or hide any composable
     showFlagVisible = true
    },content = {
    // insert the flag compose here, with if condition
    if(showFlagVisible){
     showFlag()
     }
    
        Text("Guess the Country")
    })
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Text("Guess-Hints")

    }
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Text("Guess the Flag")
    }
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Text("Advanced Level")
    }
    }
    }

    @Composable
   fun showFlag() {
  val imagenum = getRandomCountry()
   if (imagenum.isNotEmpty()) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = getResourceId(imagenum)),
        contentDescription = "Country Image"
    )
   }
   }
```

I hope  this helpful, if not

**root cause**

the showFlag() is a composable function, try to insert this inside of a non composable Callback **onclick()** function in button caused the error,

**to fix this**

you have to create a boolean state like

```
var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

like this, and change the state on onclick function,
would fix this,

Comment: sure, first i introduced a variable `showFlagVisible` , then i change the state in `onclick()`
put the `showFlag()` composable inside of the Button Content , with a if condition.

Comment: @StackMan If this helps, please upvote and accept the answer. Karma is Stackoverflow's way of saying thanks.